# 1-D Laplacian on an ellipse

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian

I would like to know if there is a simple formula for the 1-D Laplacian $\Delta$ on an Ellipse

$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^{2}=1.$$ So far I've considered the following options

1) I first tried to write $\Delta$  in terms of the Arclenght of the ellipse, but since the Arclenght is given in terms of a difficult integral this was a dead end.

2) Polar coordinates: The ellipse can be parametrized by $$x = r\cos\theta,
$$ $$y = r\sin\theta,
 $$

where $$r=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^{2}\cos^{2}\theta+a^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}}.$$

The Laplacian in polar coordinates is
$$\Delta=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta^{2}}$$

So the chain rule can be used to write $\Delta$ in terms only on  $\theta$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$, but the result is a nigthmare.

3) The ellipse can also be parametrized by $$x = a\cos\theta,
$$ $$y = b\sin\theta,
 $$

where $\theta$ here is not the polar angle. I have no Idea where to start in this case.

4) It also crossed my mind that $\Delta\sim\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta^{2}}$ like for a circle, but that seems too simple to be true.

Comment: What do you mean by 1D Laplacian on ellipses? Ellipse is a two-dimensional domain?

Comment: The Ellipse can be thought as a 1-D manifold.

Comment: Fair enough. For ellipses you would want to use elliptic coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system

Comment: Why are you using the Laplacian in 2D polar coordinates in (2)?

Comment: Because In the end I can write the differential operator solely in terms of $\theta$. Not saying is was good idea, though.